# App link in facebook open graph story does not work on mobile

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an android fitness app which can post activity to facebook via the open graph course and fitness objects. The problem I am having is with the link to my app inside the [posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPqAW.png).

If i click on the app name from a web browser I am taken to my website. However if I click the same link from inside Facebook's native mobile apps I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLFv2.png).

Is there a property I need to set somewhere on either of my open graph objects to get the mobile links to go to the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Apps are not available when using a mobile device.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/435173473172584/ for more info.